# webgl manipulating two textures on one square

Tags: javascript, html, textures, webgl

I saw this yesterday at

http://www.buzzfeed.com/kellyoakes/space-pictures-that-will-actually-make-you-think#.lhw29D3BMV

The first image has 2 textures that you can slide your mouse back and forth to change the boundary of the 2 textures. I thought this looked really interesting and wanted to try it.

My thoughts are, would I need to draw 2 squares and update their vertices every time the mouse moves and reset the buffer to these new points? It seems like there might be an easier and more efficient way so I thought I'd see if anyone had any ideas.

Comment: There are a ton of ways to implement something like this in WebGL, depending on the requirements. If you were to strictly replicate the linked content just use plain HTML, no need to use WebGL for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using plain HTML is certainly one way, as suggested by LJ_1102, and for this needs, maybe a simpler one too.

The process to create this effect with webGL would be as follows:

create canvas, draw one square (two triangles in total) over entire canvas, take mouse position on the canvas and calculate percentage of how far left/right is it from one of the edges; and for that square use some fragment shader similar as this one bellow.

```
uniform float percentage;
uniform vec2 canvas_size;
uniform sampler2D left_image;
uniform sampler2D right_image;

void main() {
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy/canvas_size;
    if ( uv.x<=percentage )
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(left_image,uv);
    else
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(right_image,uv);

}
```